# Custom Camera/Object Axis In Three Js? (For First Person)

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, axis

I have a possibly beginner question regarding camera rotation in threejs, I am beginning to work on a first person game, the camera controls however have a small issue: if I look up and down they seem to work fine, but if I step to the side of my object and use them then the object (cube) does a circle around the center of my screen.

A breakdown of my code:

Pointer lock tells me when the mouse moves, and I use it for back and forth movement:

```
    camera.rotation.y += movementX;
```

this works fine, because the y axis will always be up and down, but it doesn't work for side to side:

```
    camera.rotation.x += movementY;
```

like I said, if I don't move from the starting position then it works fine, otherwise it gets messed up.

I am basically looking for something like:
        camera.rotateX(a number);

which is like translateX(), it uses local object axis, not parallel to world axis.

I know about first person controls, but I would prefer to not use them, I would prefer code that is longer but more understandable (if possible/necessary).

Sorry For length of question :)

Comment: `camera.rotateX( angle );` and  `camera.rotateY( angle );` do what you describe.

Comment: That is so strange, I thought that I tried that, but thanks!